# Add javascript to generated html test page for Silverlight project

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

VS2010, Silverlight 4.0.

Does anyone know if there is a way to have Visual Studio add javascript (or anything for that matter) to the html test page it generates when compiling a silverlight project for debug?  Does it use a template, and if so, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting question!
I've tried to do something like that and finally found raw but pretty working solution:

First of all you should set specific page by using Properties -> Debug -> Specific Page.
My page example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>
    <title>SilverlightApplication1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fillWithData">
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost" style="height: 100%; text-align:center">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="30%" height="30%">
          <param name="source" value="file:///C:/Users/Igor/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MobileTest/SilverlightApplication1/Bin/Debug/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: blank script and div elements is important! we'll load dynamic js/html into them.

My silverlight xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument hostPage = HtmlPage.Document;

        ScriptObject obj = hostPage.GetElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        obj.SetProperty("innerHTML", "function alertonclick() { alert('Amazing! I am dynamic javascript!'); }");    

        HtmlElement ipAddressHtml = hostPage.GetElementById("fillWithData");
        ipAddressHtml.SetProperty("innerHTML", @"<input id=""Button1"" type=""button"" value=""button"" onclick=""alertonclick();"" />");
    }
}
```

VERY IMPORTANT NOTE: I've tested this code and it works *only* under Opera. 
If you need to test something using some other browser then you sould inline javascript directly into element.

Example:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument hostPage = HtmlPage.Document;

        HtmlElement ipAddressHtml = hostPage.GetElementById("fillWithData");
        ipAddressHtml.SetProperty("innerHTML", @"<input id=""Button1"" type=""button"" value=""button"" onclick=""alert('Amazing! I am dynamic javascript!');"" />");
    }
}
```

This code works well under IE/FF/Chrome/Opera (of course :) ).
As for me I like first example with both dynamic js and html. And I'm pretty sure that it's possible to fix it and make acceptable by other browser not just Opera.
I hope that my examples will help you =)